# Verify that an Option has been Selected in a Drop Down Box

Tags: javascript, forms, select

On 
http://www.greekforme.com/999-apron-01.html, there are several Drop Down boxes.

The script called 'verifyselection' is supposed to show a pop-up box if the user does not change the drop down from 'Select an Option Below'

```
function verifyselection(form) 
{
    // result function
    var blnResult = true;
    // temp name form control
    var nameControl = "";
    // array of name of radio form controls
    var arrNameControl = new Array();
    // array of value checked of radio form controls
    var arrValueControl = new Array();
    // flag existence form control in array
    var isExistOnArray = false;

    // loop on all elements of form
    for(i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
        // check type form control
        if(form.elements[i].type=="radio") {
            // save name form control
            nameControl = form.elements[i].name;
            // reset flag existence form control in array
            isExistOnArray = false;
            // loop on all found radio form control
            for(j=0; j<arrNameControl.length; j++){
                // if giving form control is exist in array
                if(arrNameControl[j] == nameControl) {
                    // set flag
                    isExistOnArray = true;
                    // break loop
                    break;
                }
            }
            // if giving form control is not exist in array
            if(isExistOnArray == false){
                // set index of array
                j = arrNameControl.length;
                // add new element to arrays
                arrNameControl[j] = nameControl;
                arrValueControl[j] = 0;
            }
            // if giving radio form control is checked
            if(form.elements[i].checked == "1"){
                arrValueControl[j] = 1;
            }
        }
                    if ((form.elements[i].selectedIndex > -1)) {
                            if (form.elements[i].selectedIndex == 0) {
                                    var opttext = form.elements[i].value.toLowerCase();
                                    if (opttext.indexOf('optional') < 0) {        
                                            blnResult = false;
                                            alert('Please select one of the options from the list');
                                            break;
                                    }
                            }

                    }
    }
    // loop on all found radio form control
    if(blnResult==true) {
                    for(j=0; j<arrNameControl.length; j++){
                // if radio group form control is checked
                if(arrValueControl[j] != 1) {
                   // set result function
                   blnResult = false;
                   // show error message
                   alert('Please select one of the options from the list');
                   break;
                   }
           }
            }
    // return result function
    return blnResult;
}
```

Currently, I can get the Pop-Up box to show when you click the Add to Cart button -

But... it still adds the items to cart.

I want the script to prevent the item from being added to cart if the user does not change the drop downs from 'Select an Option Below'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling this function from? If it's in an onsubmit handler, the *handler* should return false. So, you should have this in your code somewhere:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    return verifyselection(this);
}
```

Or, in html:

```
<form onsubmit="return verifyselection(this);" ...>
```

The important thing here being the `return` part. When the handler returns `false`, the default action won't be taken. In this case, the form won't submit.

Comment: Ah, I now see your link, and I also see that you're already doing this. I'll keep looking :)

Comment: Thanks for rechecking - yes, the 'return' is included with the onsubmit.  This one has perplexed me for sometime!

Comment: Hi, I don't have time to debug it right now, but do you have the opportunity to use a framework like jQuery or something? That would bring down the code to something like `$(form).submit(function() { return $('select option:selected[value!=""], input[type=radio][value!=""]').length > 0});` :)